# improve modem receptivity

Tags: connection, modem, performance

I have a CDMA modem that I use to access the internet.

I'm having some network issue. When I browse outside the room, I am connected and everything's fine. but when I enter the room(which is 3 cm away) , I lose connection.

is there a way to capture the waves from outside the room and drive them inside the room ? maybe using an antenna ? or something else ?

is there any way to improve the connection inside when you know that connection's good 1 or 2 cm away ?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand them, your two options are:

1. If your CDMA modem supports it, use an antenna outside the [Faraday Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) you seem to be in.
2. If your CDMA provider supports them, get a femto-cell inside the cage.

Comment: Always give props to someone who knows what a Faraday Cage is.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the model of your CDMA modem, but an antenna will work great.  I have bought a few for employees and they have helped out greatly with their aircard connection reliability.